Problem using the CONTAINS statement in FTN95
I am trying to write a very simple program using the Silverfrost FTN95 compiler in the Plato development platform. However, despite the Module having a CONTAINS statement it refuses to compile the module because it has an executable line it it. Any suggestions?
Here is the code:
MODULE mDialog1
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRIVATE; PUBLIC
  INTEGER :: easting, northing, nrp, roofs, rb1
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: roof_area, pitch
  CHARACTER(len=256) :: buffer
  INTEGER :: iw
END MODULE mDialog1

MODULE mDialog2
  USE mDialog1
  CONTAINS
  IMPLICIT NONE
  easting =456654
END MODULE mDialog2`

This generates the following message:

C:\Users\Robin\Documents\Testclearwin\FreeFormat1.F95(14) : error 853 - Executable statements are not allowed inside a MODULE (unless in CONTAINS)

I have tried changing the position of the CONTAINS statement and using fixed and free format. I was expecting it to compile properly.
